# How to remove the colorbar from filled.contour in R

Tags: r, plot, legend, contour

I have been trying to remove the colorbar from `filled.contour` plots in the R-programming language, as it seems to me that in some cases it may be redundant. Here is an example.

```
cols = heat.colors(100, rev = TRUE)
filled.contour(volcano, nlevels = 100, col = cols, plot.axes = {
  axis(1)
  axis(2)
  contour(volcano, add = TRUE, lwd = 2, labcex = 1.2)
  box()
})
```

I believe the plot would look better without this cluster of colors on the right, which is very difficult to read anyway. Could you please tell me if/how this can be accomplised?

Thank you.

Comment: Relevant https://stackoverflow.com/q/16774928/680068 See this linked post, suggesting to use `.filled.contour`, couldn't make it work, apologies for closing your post earlier.